# Printing a degree symbol (°) yields "unkown symbol" (question mark in romb)

Tags: python, python-3.7

Printing degree symbol (°) doesn't work for me (using Python 3.7).
I am using Windows 10, Sublime Text 3 and I use the following encoding on top of the file I am working with:

`# -*- coding: utf8 -*-`

It, however, works when built with Python 2.7.

An example:

```
temperature = str(26) + '°C'
print(temperature)
```

outputs `26�C` in Python 3.7 and `26°C` in Python 2.7.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you attempt to use the same code directly in the python interpreter, does it yield the same result?

Comment: It actually works in the python interpreter. I changed the encoding to cp1252, and it works when I build with Sublime Text.

Comment: Good to hear. Make sure to submit that as an answer to your question - that's allowed and encouraged!